# ASP.Net MVC If Clause being Ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

my if clause is being ignored, even though that the variable that is being compared has a value and if it has a value and it's true, then it does something, but the program doesn't even read the clause, it just jumps, I saw that with a break point.

This is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        string result = null;
        try
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                result = HIQResources.errorMessageUnknownAction;
                return new JsonResult { Data = result };
            }    
            StudentViewModel vm = new StudentViewModel();
            StudentDetail studentDetail = studentManager.GetStudentDetailById(id.Value);
            if (studentDetail == null)
            {
                result = HIQResources.errorMessageUnknownRecord;
                return new JsonResult { Data = result };
            } 
                int deleteResult = studentManager.Delete(id.Value);    
                if (deleteResult == 1)
                {
                    vm.Alert.SetSuccessMessage(HIQResources.messageOperationSuccess);
                    TempData["alert"] = vm.Alert;    
                    result = HIQResources.messageOperationSuccess;
                    return new JsonResult { Data = result };
                }                
                vm.Alert.SetErrorMessage(HIQResources.errorMessageUnableToExecuteOperation);
                TempData["alert"] = vm.Alert;
                result = HIQResources.errorMessageUnableToExecuteOperation;
                return new JsonResult { Data = result };
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            Log.AddLogRecord(LogManager.LogType.Warning, LogManager.LogPriority.Low, LogManager.LogCategory.Teacher, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, base.GetLoggedUser());

            result = HIQResources.errorMessageUnableToDeleteRecord;
            return new JsonResult { Data = result };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.AddLogRecord(LogManager.LogType.Error, LogManager.LogPriority.High, LogManager.LogCategory.Inscription, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, base.GetLoggedUser());

            result = HIQResources.errorMessageExceptionOccurred;
            return new JsonResult { Data = result };
        }
    }
```

This is all being triggered by a button which is calling these methods with Javascript:

```
   $(function () {
            var id;
            var button;

            $(".btnDeleteArgs").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                button = $(e.target);
                id = button.attr('data-hiq-student-id');               
            });    

            $('#ModalDeleteButton').on("click", function (e) {                  
                var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
                $.post("/Student/Delete/",
                    {
                        __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                        id: id                            
                    },

                    function (data) {
                        $('#myModal .close').click();
                        var baseurl = '@Url.Action("Index")';    
                        var url = baseurl + "?message=" + data;
                        window.location.href = url;
                    });    
            });
```

To be honest, I don't think that the Javascript is the problem because the problem starts at the controller, which is jumping that 'if' clause, it doesn't even execute!!!

Comment: `if (deleteResult == 1)` => what's the value of `deleteResult` (and also `studentDetail`)? The condition skipped if `deleteResult` is not equal as 1, or `studentDetail` is not null.

Comment: This can't be your complete code as it wouldn't compile. Please tell us *which* if statement is not working and what the values of the variables are.

Comment: mostly `deleteResult` is either 0 or `>1`

Comment: No, it is return to compare if it's true or false, the deleteResult is the ID of the profile that I want to delete which is found when I click the delete button

Comment: Well, you're not explaining methods which potentially returning false condition: `studentManager.GetStudentDetailById(id.Value)` & `studentManager.Delete(id.Value)`. What exactly the methods doing?

Comment: Recompile your application. Put a breakpoint on `string result = null;` and step through it line by line. In your post, after each line of code add a comment saying whether that line executed or not.

Comment: The " int deleteResult = teacherManager.Delete(id.Value);" is returning 0 for no reason because the "id.Value" is returning the value that I want and is doing everything right, but still, the "DeleteResult" is coming as 0 and not 1.

Comment: post the code for `studentManager.Delete(id.Value)`

Comment: The post code for "studentManager.Delete is this :
 public int Delete(int id)
        {
            return dao.Delete(id);
        }
"dao" is a global variable.

Comment: It's probably because the code is a little hard to read, post the Delete method, including the global variable. Only show the problematic code, including nested methods, Omit the rest. Create a unit test too!

Answer (score 0):

You said in comment *the deleteResult is the ID of the profile that I want to delete* ... in that case your `if` condition should be

```
if (deleteResult == id.Value)
{
```

Comment: The problem is that it is jumping the If Statment, it isn't even reading it.

Comment: `deleteResult` value is output of `studentManager.Delete(id.Value)` method, without knowing the method body it's hard to tell if student with certain `id` is deleted & resulting `1`.

Comment: @PauloMartins, that's not possible ... it will only skip the condition block if the condition not met (or you don't have any pre-processor directive defined in there)

Comment: I found that the value is returning null

Comment: @PauloMartins Nah, why not including the method contents which returns null value? Use debugging with breakpoint to inspect `studentDetail` & `deleteResult` values.

Comment: I already inspected, the "StudentDetal" is returning a valid value but the "DeteResult" is getting a value of 0 for some reason..